# Webpack concatenate two CSS files and an SCSS file into one CSS file

Tags: css, merge, sass, concatenation, webpack

I'm struggling to get webpack to do what I want here. Basically, I'm trying to feed in two CSS files and an SCSS file, and output one CSS file from this.

My code so far is:

```
'use strict';

var webpack = require('webpack');

var webpackDir = __dirname;

let path = require('path');
let nodeModulesPath = path.join(webpackDir, 'node_modules');

//Process the SCSS
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
let extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/[name].css',{allChunks: true});

function isDev() {

    var isDev = true;

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

        isDev = false;
    }

    return isDev;
}

var definePlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    __DEV__: isDev()
});

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: [webpackDir + '/node_modules'],
        alias: {
            rootReducers: path.join(webpackDir, '../../../../../themes/myProject-base/lib/myProject-core/register/myProject-redux-base/base-reducers'),
            rootActions: path.join(webpackDir, '../../../../../themes/myProject-base/lib/myProject-core/register/myProject-redux-base/base-actions'),
            rootUtils: path.join(webpackDir, '../../../../../themes/myProject-base/lib/myProject-core/register/myProject-redux-base/base-utils'),
            lunchMenusReducers: path.join(webpackDir, '/src/lunch-menus-common-js/reducers/lunch-menus-reducers'),
            lunchMenusActions: path.join(webpackDir, '/src/lunch-menus-common-js/actions/lunch-menus-actions'),
            lunchMenusConfigureStore: path.join(webpackDir, '/src/lunch-menus-common-js/configureStore')
        }
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        root: nodeModulesPath
    },
    entry: {
        backend: path.resolve(webpackDir + '/src/components/index.js'),
        widgetfrontend: path.join(webpackDir, '../../../includes/widget/public-js/scripts/main.js'),
        widgetbackend: path.join(webpackDir, '../../../includes/widget/js/scripts/main.js'),
        myProjectLunchMenusAdmin: [
            path.join(webpackDir, '../../scss/myProject-lunch-menus-admin.scss'),
            path.join(nodeModulesPath + 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.min.css'),
            path.join(nodeModulesPath + 'node_modules/quill/dist/*.css')
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(webpackDir + '/../'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        devtoolLineToLine: true
    },
    plugins: isDev() !== true ? [
        extractCSS,
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true}),
        definePlugin
    ] : [
        extractCSS,
        definePlugin
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /(src|myProject-base|widget)\/.+.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: [
                        require.resolve('babel-preset-es2015'),
                        require.resolve('babel-preset-react'),
                        require.resolve('babel-preset-stage-0')
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/i,
                loader: extractCSS.extract(['css','sass'])
            },
            {
                test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$|\.woff$|\.ttf$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'file'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The area of focus is `myProjectLunchMenusAdmin` - as it's not taking in the CSS + SCSS files and outputting one CSS file.

The error(s) I get are:

```
ERROR in multi myProjectLunchMenusAdmin
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' /Users/joneslloyd/Documents/MAMP/myProjectv2/wp-content/plugins/myProject-lunch-menus/admin/js/scripts/node_modules/node_modules/quill/dist/*.css in /Users/joneslloyd/Documents/MAMP/myProjectv2/wp-content/plugins/myProject-lunch-menus/admin/js/scripts
 @ multi myProjectLunchMenusAdmin

ERROR in ./~/react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.min.css
Module parse failed: /Users/joneslloyd/Documents/MAMP/myProjectv2/wp-content/plugins/myProject-lunch-menus/admin/js/scripts/node_modules/react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.min.css Line 1: Unexpected token .
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

At this stage, even a pointer/suggestion would be really useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with this config.

- [`modulesDirectories`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-modulesdirectories) should be an array of directory *names* that will be resolved like `node_modules` (that is: traversing the directory tree and looking for a `node_modules` folder). *Do not put actual paths in this array*. This is one of the most common errors I see in webpack configs. Since npm is the most prominent package manager, you usually don't need to set this option as it already defaults to `node_modules`.
- The named chunk `myProjectLunchMenusAdmin` references CSS files, but you did not activate the css-loader for the `.css` extension. That's basically what the `Module parse failed` error is trying to say.
- The named chunk `myProjectLunchMenusAdmin` references the glob pattern `node_modules/quill/dist/*.css`. Webpack does not understand glob patterns. In your case, it tries to include a file actually named `*.css` which is what the `Module not found` error is trying to tell. You need to pass webpack only one file and webpack will figure out the dependency graph. For example: If file `main.css` imports `some-other-file.css`, it will include that file too and so on. By doing that, webpack will only include files that are actually needed because they are referenced in your program. (Btw: `node_modules/node_modules` does not look correct)
- Using a relative path for the first argument of the `ExtractTextPlugin` is probably invalid. I don't know if that actually works. You should just give a filename and webpack will emit the extracted and unified CSS into a file with that name in the specified `output.path`. The `output.path` is usually a flat folder without sub-directories. If you need to move the bundled files around afterwards, you should separate that from your webpack build. That's just another build step.
- `resolveLoader.root` does not need to be modified as long as you're installing your loaders via npm (which I strongly recommend).

I've tried to fix the given config. Since I don't know your project, there is not guarantee that this will work.

```
'use strict';

let webpack = require('webpack');

let path = require('path');
let nodeModulesPath = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules');

//Process the SCSS
let ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
let extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css',{allChunks: true});
let isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

var definePlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    __DEV__: isDev
});

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            rootReducers: path.join(__dirname, '../../../../../themes/myProject-base/lib/myProject-core/register/myProject-redux-base/base-reducers'),
            rootActions: path.join(__dirname, '../../../../../themes/myProject-base/lib/myProject-core/register/myProject-redux-base/base-actions'),
            rootUtils: path.join(__dirname, '../../../../../themes/myProject-base/lib/myProject-core/register/myProject-redux-base/base-utils'),
            lunchMenusReducers: path.join(__dirname, 'src/lunch-menus-common-js/reducers/lunch-menus-reducers'),
            lunchMenusActions: path.join(__dirname, 'src/lunch-menus-common-js/actions/lunch-menus-actions'),
            lunchMenusConfigureStore: path.join(__dirname, 'src/lunch-menus-common-js/configureStore')
        }
    },
    entry: {
        backend: path.join(__dirname, 'src/components/index.js'),
        widgetfrontend: path.join(__dirname, '../../../includes/widget/public-js/scripts/main.js'),
        widgetbackend: path.join(__dirname, '../../../includes/widget/js/scripts/main.js'),
        myProjectLunchMenusAdmin: [
            path.join(__dirname, '../../scss/myProject-lunch-menus-admin.scss'),
            path.join(nodeModulesPath, 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.min.css'),
            path.join(nodeModulesPath, 'quill/dist/quill.base.css'),
            path.join(nodeModulesPath, 'quill/dist/quill.snow.css')
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        devtoolLineToLine: true
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS,
        definePlugin
    ].concat(isDev ? [

    ] : [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true})
    ]),
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /(src|myProject-base|widget)\/.+.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: [
                        require.resolve('babel-preset-es2015'),
                        require.resolve('babel-preset-react'),
                        require.resolve('babel-preset-stage-0')
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                loader: extractCSS.extract(['css'])
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/i,
                loader: extractCSS.extract(['css','sass'])
            },
            {
                test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$|\.woff$|\.ttf$/,
                loader: 'file'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: That works absolutely brilliantly. Thanks a lot!

The only edits I had to make were for the CSS output path (it was outputting into the same dir as the SCSS files), and I had to add this back in:
    `resolveLoader: {
        root: nodeModulesPath
    },`
(Just because the rootReducers and rootActions need to know about node_modules).

Thanks a lot for your help - really appreciated!

Comment: Actually one other thing I noticed: It outputs an identically named JS file, as well as the CSS file!

So in my CSS folder I correctly have myProjectLunchMenusAdmin.css, but in the folder of my webpack config file, I have myProjectLunchMenusAdmin.js

Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: I'm afraid, no. Because webpack assumes all file types to be somehow embedded in JavaScript. The bundled CSS for example is just a JavaScript string. The ExtractTextWebpackPlugin just puts that string into a separate file. The surrounding CommonJS module stays in the JavaScript file, although there is no actual code anymore in your case.

Comment: We had a discussion about whether webpack should be able to understand other file types than JavaScript: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/536

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and for the link! I'll check it out!